# C++ Advantage of Proxy Classes

Tags: c++, c++11

Scott Meyers says in "Effective Modern C++" that the expression

`Matrix sum = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4`

(where all objects have type `Matrix`) "can be computed much more efficiently if `operator+` for `Matrix` objects returns a proxy for the result instead of the result itself. That is, `operator+` for two `Matrix` objects would return an object of a proxy class such as `Sum<Matrix, Matrix>` instead of a `Matrix` object. This would encode the entire initialization expression, i.e., be something like `Sum<Sum<Sum<Matrix, Matrix>, Matrix>, Matrix>`.".

Now, I understand that proxy classes emulate behaviour of some other classes and do implicit converisons, but how and why is proxy approach in this case more efficient?

Best regards

Comment: Well, for one thing, in your code example the proxy approach wouldn't require any addition to be done, since you never read from `sum`.

Comment: I am not familiar with C++ proxy, but that looks like chained lazy evaluation, which delays the evaluation of a chain operations until you need the result.

Comment: Maybe **Expression Templates** is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that `Matrix` might be an arbitrary-sized matrix, so it has to allocate storage for its elements from the heap. Adding two matrices together means allocating storage and doing the element-wise copy.

In the expression above, that means allocating storage once for `(m1 + m2)`, for adding the result of that to `m3`, and a third time for adding that to `m4`. (Move semantics can reduce this cost.)

If the addition instead returns a proxy that just represents the addition while holding references to the things being added together, you only allocate once, for the final assignment.

With more work behind the scenes, it's possible to be even more lazy and calculate only those elements of the result matrix that are needed, on-demand.

However, these things are always a trade-off and you need to evaluate the costs and benefits in each case.

Comment: If the first paramenter of each operator+ is passed by-copy, the compiler can optimize the copies away by just operating on the result object, as explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators

So you can avoid the proxy.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Yes, copy elision and move semantics can reduce the need for allocations, but for example in `(a + b) * (c + d)`, you still have at least two allocations, where expression templates can eliminate all but one.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate how it works in code, I have implemented an example here [invisible proxy](https://github.com/xeonqq/matrix_template_expression/blob/7eabd36a32a8c405be2bc9d7199e6beeb90c36a9/includes/matrix.h) which mimics the description from the book.

As written in the example, lazy evaluation happens at the copy Ctor of Matrix (Line 30), where calculation is actually performed. It is more efficient, because no temporary object is created, rather calculated directly in place.

I also did a performance comparison using callgrind between traditional OO based implementation and the template expression based implementation.

Setup:

- Matrix Size: (1, 2000)
- Expression to be evaluated: mat_a + mat_a + mat_a + mat_b + mat_c;

Result:

[template expression](https://github.com/xeonqq/matrix_template_expression/blob/7eabd36a32a8c405be2bc9d7199e6beeb90c36a9/profile/matrix_template_expression.png) (cost: 618037)

vs

[object oriented + operator](https://github.com/xeonqq/matrix_template_expression/blob/7cc9f4ae82b6503ba913549b3ae38406da70552d/profile/matrix_oo_operator_plus.png) (cost: 944424)